# Media server (Mediatomb) accessible over internet

Tags: mediaserver, mediatomb

I currently have a server installed with Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 (first time using Linux) which I would like to configure as a media server. Additionaly, I have installed Samba, OpenSSH, Webmin and Mediatomb.

At the moment, I created a shared folder that is accessible within the network, and I can play the files I have added in Mediatomb using Windows Media Player locally. I can also play it on my Android devices over the internet using UPnPlay (in combination with an SSH tunnel through Connectbot). I would also like to stream my music with Mediatomb to a Windows (7) computer outside the local network, but have not been able to get this to work.

I am using Putty to tunnel the required ports, in much the same way as I am doing this with Connectbot. Doing this, I can access the Mediatomb GUI, Webmin and use VNC, but I can't seem to find the server as a UPnP device, or see it at all. I have tried several media players (Windows Media Player, VLC, XBMC, Foobar2000) but haven't been able to connect with them so far.

Does anyone know if it is possible to access Mediatomb outside a local network on a Windows 7 system, or should I look into other software for this (Plex, Subsonic?).